# Re-render class in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

new to React, I'm testing to write a small program where you select a name in a list, and then a proverb should be displayed. The event handler handleAuthorClick is called, and setState is also called, but the new text is not displayed.

Why?

```
class AuthorList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: -1,
      text: "When in Rome do as the Romans",
    }
  }

  handleAuthorClick()
  {
       let txt = "initial value";
       var sel = document.getElementById("author-list"); 
       switch (parseInt(sel.value))
        {
          case 12 : txt = "When in Rome do as the Romans"; break;
          case 33: txt = "If you tell the truth, you don't have to remember anything.";break;
          case 256: txt = "History will be kind to me for I intend to write it";break;
          default:;
        }
       this.setState({text: txt});
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div className="author-list">
          <h2>Author List</h2>
          <select id='author-list' name='author-list' size='15' onClick={() => this.handleAuthorClick()>
             <option value="12">Unknown</option>
             <option value="33">Mark Twain</option>
             <option value="256">Winston Churchill</option>
          </select>
          <h2>Proverbs</h2>
          {this.props.text}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

class ProVerbMain extends React.Component {
      render() {
      return (
        <div className="proverb">
          <h1>Dans proverbs</h1>
          <div className="author-list">
            <AuthorList text = 'Initial value'/>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

ReactDOM.render(<ProVerbMain />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: `text` is in state, not props. Also there's almost never any good reason to dig into the DOM to get values like this, at least for simple stuff like normal form elements.

Comment: Text property value won't change after setState, try writing this.state.text || this.props.text. You should use onChange instead of onClick in select tag.

Comment: Don't mix the state and props name. And yes onChange() should be the candidate to work here not onClick().

Comment: Actually yes, you can get rid of initial text property and use only state object to display your text.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.state.text` instead of `this.props.text`, because it's a local state of your component. When you use `this.props.text` your component doesn't know the new state for new render.
You should use `onChange()` event instead of `onClick()` in select option

Comment: This doesn't address the biggest issue (and the OP states it works, although I agree in should be `onChange`).

Comment: Yeah, but I think his issue is using this.props.text in render

Comment: Yes, as I said in my comment, and you edited your question to answer.

Comment: Yes, I am a newbie. I just want to help

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you , use `onChange` rather than `onClick`.
also you were using class methods `handleAuthorClick()` and not even binding them to class's `this` as function have their own `this` scope , you can't access class members from inside that function, that's why either use `() => {}` or use `.bind(this)` in class's constructor

EDIT: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
class AuthorList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: -1,
      text: "When in Rome do as the Romans"
    };
  //this.handleAuthorClick = this.handleAuthorClick.bind(this); 
  }

  handleAuthorClick = e => {
    let txt = this.props.text;
    console.log(e.target.value);
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "12":
        txt = "When in Rome do as the Romans";
        break;
      case "33":
        txt = "If you tell the truth, you don't have to remember anything.";
        break;
      case "256":
        txt = "History will be kind to me for I intend to write it";
        break;
      default:
    }
    // alert(txt);
    this.setState({ text: txt });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="author-list">
        <h2>Author List</h2>
        <select name="author-list" size="15" onChange={this.handleAuthorClick}>
          <option value="12">Unknown</option>
          <option value="33">Mark Twain</option>
          <option value="256">Winston Churchill</option>
        </select>
        <h2>Proverbs</h2>
        {this.state.text}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ProVerbMain extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="proverb">
        <h1>Dans proverbs</h1>
        <div className="author-list">
          <AuthorList text="Initial value" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ProVerbMain />, rootElement);
```

demo :
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-yj3s5

Answer (score 0):

You've to use state instead of props.

```
import React from "react";

class AuthorList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: -1,
      text: "When in Rome do as the Romans"
    };
  }

  handleAuthorClick() {
    let txt = "initial value";
    var sel = document.getElementById("author-list");
    switch (parseInt(sel.value, 10)) {
      case 12:
        txt = "When in Rome do as the Romans";
        break;
      case 33:
        txt = "If you tell the truth, you don't have to remember anything.";
        break;
      case 256:
        txt = "History will be kind to me for I intend to write it";
        break;
      default:
    }
    //alert(txt);
    this.setState({ text: txt });
  }

  render() {
    const { text } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="author-list">
        <h2>Author List</h2>
        <select
          id="author-list"
          name="author-list"
          size="15"
          onClick={() => this.handleAuthorClick()}
        >
          <option value="12">Unknown</option>
          <option value="33">Mark Twain</option>
          <option value="256">Winston Churchill</option>
        </select>
        <h2>Proverbs</h2>
        {text}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ProVerbMain extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="proverb">
        <h1>Dans proverbs</h1>
        <div className="author-list">
          <AuthorList text="Initial value" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProVerbMain;
```

And here is your working sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/still-grass-r5iz9/